# Change of @Binding values does not affect view

Tags: swiftui

I have a struct, which has a private `Array` inside. All operations on this array have to be *different than normal* — adding element to array affects other elements. Common `append`, `insert` or `delete` are forbidden.

Every element of an array has nested array of some data.

And I made views hierarchy to edit data:

```
struct ContentView<Axis>: View 
where Axis: StyledAxisProtocol
{
    @State var axes = Axes<Axis>()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
 // View responds to new added axis:
                Button(action: {axes.addAxis()},
                       label: {Text("Add Axis")})
            }
            ForEach(axes.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                StyledAxisView(axes: $axes, axisIndex: index)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct StyledAxisView<Axis>: View 
where Axis: StyledAxisProtocol
{
    @Binding var axes: Axes<Axis>
    var axisIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GroupBox {
                HStack {
                    TextField("", text: $axes[axisIndex].name)
//If I move a slider (change some parameter of `axis` - view refreshes                    
                    Slider(value: $axes[axisIndex].position,
                           in: axes[axisIndex].bounds)
// View does not react to new instance, need to move slider to update a view                     
                    Button(action: {
                        axes.addInstance(to: axisIndex) 
                    },
                           label: {
                        Text("Add Style to \(axes[axisIndex].name)")
                    })
                }
                AxisStyleInstacesView(axis: $axes[axisIndex])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both operations are defined as mutating:

```
public extension Axes {
    mutating func addAxis() {
        _axes.operation(.add)
    }
    
    mutating func addInstance(to axisIndex: Int) {
        _axes.addInstance(to: axisIndex)
    }
}
```

Also every *deeper* operations does not changes view till I change some parameter of highest level, ie. `axis.position` by moving slider.
I tried to change `struct Axes` to `Observable class` but it was worse: no view reaction to adding axes. I'm confused.
How to deal with it?

I found if I will do something stupid, it start to work:

```
public extension Array where Element: StyledAxisProtocol {
    mutating func addInstance(to axisIndex: Int) 
    {
        var newInstance = Element.AxisStyleInstance()
        let at = self[axisIndex].position
        newInstance.name = "\(self[axisIndex].shortName):\(String(format:"%.0f", Double(at)))"
        
        newInstance.axisEdgesValues = Array<Double>(repeating: at, 
                                                    count: oneAxisEdgesCount)
        self[axisIndex].axisInstances.append(newInstance)
// This is stupid:
        self[axisIndex] = self[axisIndex]
        distribute()
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Show some code that I can copy and paste directly into a blank Xcode project and reproduce the issue.

Comment: It will taka a while. OK?

Comment: Sure. Remember to make it as *minimal* as possible.

Comment: It's why it will take a moment ;)

Comment: When I made a minimal example - it works... :( I need to search deeper. I need to eat something now.

Comment: I found it very stupid: to trigger change I added `self[axisIndex] = self[axisIndex]` in function which adds Instance. WTF???? It's ugly.

Answer (score -1):

`ForEach` is a `View` not a loop, you can't use it with indices and `id: \.self` is an error (although the compiler doesn't show it). The correct way to use `ForEach` with bindings is like this:

```
ForEach($axes) { $axis in
    StyledAxisView(axis: $axis)
```

```
struct Axis: Identifable {
    let id = UUID()
```

Comment: Thank you! Somehow it's hard for me to accept this :)

Comment: But what I should  do if I have 3rd party package or library, and I cannot add Identifiable protocol?

Comment: You could put their struct inside your own one which is `Identifiable`.

Comment: But why `id:\.self` for indices is illegal? I found it in many places, ForEach offers it., seems to work...

Comment: The docs state "Either the collection’s elements must conform to Identifiable or you need to provide an id parameter to the ForEach initializer." Obviously this means the identifier for the data cant be the data itself, i.e. it cant be `self`, otherwise why would there even be an `id` param? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach

Comment: @Łukasz watching "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC will give a good explanation of why indices are not reliably identifiers.

Comment: I guess I should have said first the id cant be an index because if item at 0 moves to 1 then the move is not detected. Also if the last item is removed then when it calls the closure on the last index again it'll crash with an out of range exception. You can find examples of that crash on SO.

Comment: But for an array of `[Double]` in `VStack` indices are only one way. Is it true?

Comment: If you have a [Double] you need to transform it into an array of Identifiable items, e.g. in a computed property